# What is the alternative for NodeBuilder()? It seems to be deprecated and I'm struggling to configure Elasticsearch in spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

This is what my code looks like at the moment. This is the configuration file needed when I load the elasticsearch.

```
public class Elastic_config {

        @Bean
        NodeBuilder nodebuilder(){
            return new NodeBuilder().Node();
        }

        @Bean
        ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchOperations() throws IOException {
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp-elastic", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));

        Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings =
                Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("http.enabled","true")
                        .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
                        .put("path.data", new File(tempFile, "data").getAbsolutePath())
                        .put("path.logs", new File(tempFile, "logs").getAbsolutePath())
                        .put("path.work", new File(tempFile, "work").getAbsolutePath())
                        .put("path.home", tempFile);

        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder())
                .local(true)
                .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
                .node()
                .client();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Transport Client instead which worked. See link
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial